# Complex NumPy Array Manipulation

Tags: arrays, numpy, indexing, include

I have two numpy arrays:
e.g.

```
np.array_1([
[5,2,0]
[4,3,0]
[4,2,0]
[3,2,1]
[4,1,1]
])

np.array_2([
[5,2,10]
[4,2,52]
[3,2,80]
[1,2,4]
[5,3,6]
])
```

In np.array_1, 0 and 1 at index 2 represent two different categories. For arguments sake say 0 = Red and 1 = Blue.

So, where the first two elements match in the two numpy arrays, I need to average the third element in np.array_2 by category. For example, [5,2,10] and [4,2,52] both match with category 0 i.e. Red. The code will return the average of the elements at index 2 for the Red category. It will also do the same for the Blue category.

I have no idea where to start with this, any ideas welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You marked your post with *Numpy* tag due to the type of source arrays,
but it is much easier and intuitive to generate your result using *Pandas*.

Start from conversion of your both arrays to *pandasonic* DataFrames.
While converting the first array, convert also *0* and *1* in the last
column to *Red* and *Blue*:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(array_1, columns=['A', 'B', 'key'])
df1.key.replace({0: 'Red', 1: 'Blue'}, inplace=True)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(array_2, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

Then, to generate the result, run:

```
result = df2.merge(df1, on=['A', 'B']).groupby('key').C.mean().rename('Mean')
```

The result is:

```
key
Blue    80
Red     31
Name: Mean, dtype: int32
```

Details:

1. `df2.merge(df1, on=['A', 'B'])` - Generates:

   ```
      A  B   C   key
   0  5  2  10   Red
   1  4  2  52   Red
   2  3  2  80  Blue
   ```

   eliminating at the same time rows which don't belong to any group
   (are neither *Red* nor *Blue*).
2. `groupby('key')` - From the above result, generates groups by *key*
   (*Red* / *Blue*).
3. `C.mean()` - the last step is to take *C* column (from each group)
   and compute its *mean*.
4. The result is a *Series* with:

   - index - the grouping key,
   - value - the value computed for the corresponding group.
5. `rename('Mean')` - Change the name from the source column name (*C*)
   to a more meaningful *Mean*.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, the 0: 'Red' and 1: 'Blue' that is in the last column in df1 comes from a pre-defined dictionary that I just need to refer back to.  I was wondering if it is possible to find out the result also with an optional argument where I would specify that I want the mean for just Red or Blue or any other colour from my pre-defined dictionary? Thank you :)